# Use of Undeclared Identifier 'dateAge'?

Tags: objective-c

I'm new to learning Objective C and I'm following some online tutorials, I seemed to be keeping up fine and then 26 videos in I'm a little confused. X-Code keeps throwing me an error for an undeclared identifier.

In Person.h I have written:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface Person : NSObject
-(void) dateAge:(int)a withIncome:(int)i;
@end
```

In Person.m I have written:

```
#import "Person.h"
@implementation Person
-(void) dateAge:(int)a withIncome:(int)i {NSLog(@"You can date girls %i years old and above", (dateAge/2+7) - (i/100000));}
@end
```

Person.m is where I am being thrown an error, I'm using the latest version of x-code and the tutorials are a year or so old, I don't know if that could be it?

main.m just says:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Person.h
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {
      Person *bucky = [[Person alloc]init];
      [bucky dateAge:65 withIncome:300000];
      }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `a` instead of `dateAge` which is the declared variable name here,

```
-(void) dateAge:(int)a withIncome:(int)i {NSLog(@"You can date girls %i years old and above", (a/2+7) - (i/100000));}
```

Comment: I feel so stupid, thank you so much, that fixed everything :)

Comment: It says I have to wait three minutes before I can accept your answer :), I will check the mark as soon as I can :), thank you again :)

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  NSLog(@"You can date girls %i years old and above", (dateAge/2+7) - (i/100000));
}
```

Instead of dateAge, use a which you are passing as a parameter like below :

```
{
  NSLog(@"You can date girls %i years old and above", (a/2+7) - (i/100000));
}
```